# Why can't I use `filename.open' instead of `open(filename)'?

Tags: ruby

In this piece of code which lets you read a file in the terminal, why do you need to use `open(filename)` rather than `filename.open`?

```
filename = ARGV.first
txt = open(filename)
puts "Here's your file #{filename}:"
print txt.read
print "Type the filename again: "
file_again = $stdin.gets.chomp
txt_again = open(file_again)
print txt_again.read
```

Comment: Why can you use `filename.open`?

Comment: What makes you think that the `String` class should be responsible for managing access to the filesystem? Or even know about what a filesystem is?

Comment: Because that's what Ruby expects you to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use `filename.open`, because filename is a String and method `open` is not defined in String

Use [File#open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-open)

```
File.open(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open("file")
```

opens a local file and returns a file object. Here [File#open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-open) is a method of File class.

```
open("file")
```

is actually [Kernel#open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-open) and looks at the string to decide what to do with it.

**Trivializing things:**

- `File.open("file")` is telling Ruby specifically to open a file.
- In case of `open("file")` Ruby examines the string `"file"` to determine what type it is (here a file) and open corresponding type else throws appropriate error.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a class for dealing with paths in an object-oriented way: [`Pathname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html)

```
require 'pathname'

loop do
  print 'Enter filename: '
  pn = Pathname(gets.chomp)
  if pn.file?
    puts "Here's your file '#{pn}':", pn.read
  elsif pn.exist?
    puts 'That is not a file.'
  else
    puts 'File does not exist.'
  end
end
```